# basic calculator, using Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: c++, string, double

I'm trying to make a basic calculator, using Reverse Polish Notation that gets input from `string` and outputs a `double`. Input is: `82+5*8-4/` what should be read as `(((8 + 2) * 5) - 8) / 4` in Standard notation.

The wanted output is 10.5 but my output is 106.962.

Can you explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

As far as i can see I'm doing something wrong in the string to double switch, but i am a novice in   C++ and i don't know what the problem is exactly.

Here's what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string input = "82+5*8-4/";
    double output, num;
    num = input.at(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < input.size() - 1; i = i + 2) {
        switch (input.at(i + 1)) {
            case '+':
                output = num + input.at(i);
                break;
            case '-':
                output = num - input.at(i);
                break;
            case '*':
                output = num * input.at(i);
                break;
            case '/':
                output = num / input.at(i);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        num = output;
    }
    std::cout << output << std::endl;    
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: There's no character encoding where e.g. `1 == '1'`. You must convert the digit character to its corresponding integer value. This is usually done by normal subtraction, as in `input[i] - '0'`.

Comment: Also how can you tell that `82` is two separate tokens `8` and `2` and `12` is the single token `12`? Your code doesn't seem to attempt to read multi-digit numbers

Comment: For RPN you need the following:
- a push operation ('enter', you can use another charater for that, e.g. #).
- a temporary string where you collect multi character numbers
- a stack of numbers
- and an operation, which also pulls numbers from the stack
Your sample string is not RPN. RPN for "(((8 + 2) * 5) - 12) / 4" would be "8#2+#5*#12-#4/", assuming "#" is your character for enter.
You probably read some more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Comment: You should insist that in the input numbers are separated by white space or operators.  This allows you to distinguish between 82 and 8 2.

Comment: I edited the question from: input = 82+5*12-4/ to: input = 82+5*8-4/. Because using multi-digit numbers was not the goal of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the comments, i got it working now:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string input = "82+5*8-4/";
    double output, num1;
    num1 = input[0] - '0';
    

    for (int i = 1; i < input.size() - 1; i = i + 2) {
        double num2 = input[i] - '0';

        switch (input.at(i + 1)) {
            case '+':
                output = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case '-':
                output = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case '*':
                output = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case '/':
                output = num1 / num2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        num1 = output;
    }
    std::cout << output << std::endl;    
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: presumably for multi digit nos you need a separator such as space between the numbers